# How to make an endomorphism of an LCA group invertible

Tags: ct.category-theory, topological-groups

Consider a pair $(G,\phi)$ where $G$ is a (discrete) Abelian group and $\phi\colon G\to G$ is an endomorphism of $G$. There is a usual trick to construct a new pair $(G',\phi')$ with the property that $\phi'$ is an automorphism, and such that $(G',\phi')$ is, in a certain sense, "as close as possible" to $(G,\phi)$. Indeed, consider the following direct system:
$$
G\overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow}G\overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow}G\overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow}G\overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow}\cdots
$$
Then one defines $G'$ as the colimit of the above system and lets $\phi'$ be the map induced by $\phi$.

Another, equivalent, approach is to see the pair $(G,\phi)$ as a $\mathbb Z[X]$-module $G_\phi$ (where multiplication by $X$ corresponds to an application of $\phi$), then $(G',\phi')$ is the pair that corresponds with the $\mathbb Z[X]$-module
$$G'_{\phi'}:=G_{\phi}\otimes_{\mathbb Z[X]}\mathbb Z[X^{\pm 1}]$$
obtained by tensoring with $\mathbb Z[X^{\pm1}]$ (the ring of Laurent polynomials). In this language it is easy to see that the obvious map $\varphi\colon G_{\phi}\to G'_{\phi'}$ satisfies a universal property, in that any morphism of $\mathbb Z[X]$-modules from $G_\phi$ to a $\mathbb Z[X]$-module $H_\psi$ with $\psi$ invertible, factors uniquely through $\varphi$ (this makes the "as close as possible" in my second sentence precise).

Now the question is, What if the $G$ is a locally compact Abelian (always Hausdorff) topological group, and $\phi$ is a continuous endomorphism? Can we do something similar to the above in this more general situation?

If it helps, I am happy to make some assumptions about $\phi$, but I am looking for a construction that works when $\phi$ is not necessarily open.

To conclude, let me precise that I am looking for functorial constructions that take as input the pair $(G,\phi)$ (with $G$ LCA and $\phi$ continuous), and give as output a pair $(G',\phi')$ with $G'$ Hausdorff topological group, $\phi'$ a topological automorphism (i.e., continuous, open and linear), that satisfy some kind of universal property as the one above.

Comment: You can consider the same construction in the category of topological groups, but the direct limit of locally compact groups is not necessarily a locally compact group.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Yes, there is that problem (which is minor for me as I am actually interested in Pontryagin reflexive groups), but the main problem I see is that the resulting group, depending on how one defines the direct limit, may fail to be Hausdorff and, in any case, the resulting map will be continuous and bijective but, as far as I am able to prove, not necessarily open. So it will not be a topological automorphism.

Comment: Whenever that colimit exists in some category, the induced endomorphism will be an automorphism. So there ist no need to worry if the map will be open. Of course the problem remains that the colimit might not exist in your desired category.

Comment: What happens if you just take the Hausdorffification of the direct limit?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think this might work. In this case the Hausdorffification is just the quotient over the closure of $0$. Still it is not clear to me that the pre-image of the closure of $0$ is the closure of $0$. If that is not the case in general, the Hausdorffification of the map we got will not be injective.

Comment: On the other hand, the Hausdorffification of the colimit (in the category of topological Abelian groups), should be, but maybe I am wrong here, the colimit in the category of Hausdorff topological Abelian groups. If that is the case one should be able to conclude "by abstract non-sense", as @JakobWerner suggested...